# What is this webview popup dialog?

Tags: android, popup

what is this kind of window that pops up referred to as?

and is there a way to apply it to my webview for popups? (I can ask this in a separate question if needed)

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose you want to show a popup windows which contain a webview from a webview in your application.

Two steps needed. First you need to Override the onJSAlert() method in the WebChromeClient class to enable popup window in webview:

```
public class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
        @Override
        public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, JsResult jsResult) {
            final JsResult finalJsResult = jsResult;
            new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext()).setMessage(message).setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    finalJsResult.confirm();
                }
            }).setCancelable(false).create().show();
            return true;
        }
    }
```

and add this to your webview:

```
MyWebChromeClient myWebChromeClient = new MyWebChromeClient();
webView.setWebChromeClient(myWebChromeClient);
```

Then you can add custom webview in your AlertDialog (to replace the AlertDialog above):

```
public OnClickListener imageButtonViewOnClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(MyActivity.this);             
            View alertDialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog_layout, null);
            WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.DialogWebView);
            myWebView.loadData(webContent, "text/html", "utf-8");
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this);
            builder.setView(alertDialogView);
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            }).show();
        }
    };
```

The xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">
<webView android:id="@+id/DialogWebView" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dip" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

Comment: Do you know why I might be getting and error at
myWebView.loadData(webContent, "text/html", "utf-8");

webContent can not be resolved?

Comment: @Colby I would like to suggest you to try a most simple webContent at first. Like "myWebView.loadData("<h1>web content</h1>", "text/ 
html", "utf-8"); ". Hope this helps.

Comment: @Colby Additionaly, you may like to know the limitation of loaddata() which can be seen here: http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/d7bf4187b731c6ae?pli=1

Comment: Oh, I get it! Thanks dude this is awesome. Like fresh muffins in the morning